# one thread print,one thread raw_input in python

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7

I want to finish a python script(func) which has below functions:

1.there are two threads,one thread print a updating line which shows the left time before input to the terminal

2.another thread waiting for my input to the terminal(`sys.stdin`)

3.my question is,while i use my func like:

```
print '''input your file path,the default value will be "/root/targets.txt":>'''
get_input_intime([''],'/root/targets.txt',20)
```

but I can not input a long file abs path,coz the first thread is always print the left time,and I want to achieve:

a)there are two lines in the terminal

b)the first line as the first thread's print string's place

c)the second line will accept my input,so i can input a file path in my need and will not be flushed by the first thread,like this:

in terminal:

#### first line:sys.stdout.write("%s seconds left...please input your chioce:>\r" % timeout)

#### second line:(wainting for my input)

4.my code is:

1)get chioce in some seconds,if no input,return the default chioce

2)the first param is a list contain undefault chioces.

eg.there are four chioce 1,2,3,4,if I want to make the default chioce as 2,then the undefault_chioce_list is ['1','3','4'],each of the list is str type.

3)the second param is the default chioce value

4)the third param is the time before input(choose)

5)the return value is the chioce from `raw_input()`

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,func,args,name=''):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name=name
        self.func=func
        self.args=args
    def run(self):
        self.result=apply(self.func,self.args)
    def get_result():
        return self.result

def get_input_intime(undefault_chioce_list,default_choose,timeout=5):
    default_choose=[default_choose]
    timeout=[timeout]
    choosed=[0]
    chioce=['']
    def print_time_func():
        while (choosed[0]==0 and timeout[0]>0):
            sys.stdout.write("%s seconds left...please input your chioce:>\r" % timeout)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(1)
            timeout[0]-=1
        if choosed[0]==0:
            chioce[0]=default_choose[0]
    def input_func():
        rlist, _, _ = select([sys.stdin], [], [], timeout[0])
        if rlist:
            chioce_and_enter = sys.stdin.readline()
            choosed[0]=1
            if chioce_and_enter[0] not in undefault_chioce_list:
                chioce[0]=default_choose[0]
            else:
                chioce[0]=chioce_and_enter[0]
            print "you choosed %s" % chioce[0]
        else:
            print "\nyou didn't input..."
            print "I will choose the default chioce for you:%s" % default_choose[0]
    time_left_thread=MyThread(print_time_func,())
    input_thread=MyThread(input_func,())
    time_left_thread.start()
    input_thread.start()
    time_left_thread.join()
    input_thread.join()
    return chioce[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally,I achieve it in below code,but can not print the left time in one line,it will print the left time in lines:
----------------------output:---------------------

20 seconds left...please input your chioce:>

19 seconds left...please input your chioce:>

18 seconds left...please input your chioce:>

17 seconds left...please input your chioce:>

16 seconds left...please input your chioce:>

15 seconds left...please input your chioce:>

14 seconds left...please input your chioce:>

> this is my choose line

you choosed d

-------------------------end---------------------

```
import threading
import time
import sys
import readline
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,func,args,name=''):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name=name
        self.func=func
        self.args=args
    def run(self):
        self.result=apply(self.func,self.args)
    def get_result():
        return self.result

def get_input_intime(undefault_chioce_list,default_choose,timeout=5):
    default_choose=[default_choose]
    timeout=[timeout]
    choosed=[0]
    chioce=['']
    def print_time_func():
        while choosed[0]==0 and timeout[0]>0:
            time.sleep(1)
            sys.stdout.write('\r'+' '*(len(readline.get_line_buffer())+2)+'\r')
            print "%s seconds left...please input your chioce:>" % timeout[0]
            sys.stdout.write('> ' + readline.get_line_buffer())
            sys.stdout.flush()
            timeout[0]-=1
        if choosed[0]==0:
            chioce[0]=default_choose[0]
    def input_func():
        while choosed[0]==0 and timeout[0]>0:
            s = raw_input('> ')
            #rlist, _, _ = select([sys.stdin], [], [], timeout[0])
            if s or len(s)==0:
                input_value=s
                choosed[0]=1
                if input_value not in undefault_chioce_list:
                    chioce[0]=default_choose[0]
                else:
                    chioce[0]=input_value
                print "you choosed %s" % chioce[0]
    time_left_thread=MyThread(print_time_func,())
    input_thread=MyThread(input_func,())
    time_left_thread.start()
    input_thread.setDaemon(True)
    input_thread.start()
    time_left_thread.join()
    if choosed[0]==0:
        print "i choose the default chioce for you:%s" % chioce[0]
    return chioce[0]
get_input_intime(['a','b','c'],'d',20)
```